# php eclipse I can't seem to open my website from eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I'm writing a website in eclipse and I'm trying to run it from inside eclipse and I keep getting object not found errors.

I'm using ubuntu and xampp I keep moving the eclipse workspace around and i can't find where it should be.  I've read that it should be in htdocs folder so thats where i put it but I still can't open and pages.

So my method would be to
right click on the page in the explorer 
run as
configure 
set the file to /practice/page.html
set the url to /htdocs/practice/page.html
run

and I get this error

object not found

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

```
Error 404
localhost
Mon 16 Jan 2012 05:09:10 PM EST
Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0c PHP/5.3.8 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Anybody have any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: Did you check error log?

Comment: Is your `DocumentRoot` really `/htdocs`? Check your Apaceh config and error logs.

Comment: by document root you mean workspace right? if so I'm sure its set to htdocs

Comment: Konsolenfreddy you were right I found another lampp folder with htdocs inside and that was the correct document root.  I moved my workspace to there (then I had to change permissions) and its working now thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If the `DocumentRoot` is `/htdocs`, shouldn't you set the URL to `/practice/page.html` instead of `/htdocs/practice/page.html`?
According to [this](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#1168),

> The main directory for all WWW documents is \xampp\htdocs. If you put a file "test.html" in this directory, you can access it with the URI "http://localhost/test.html".

Comment: I've tried that as well I've moved the workspace to a few different places. 
I just copied and pasted my page.html file and put it in htdocs and I couldn't open it with  "http://localhost/page.html"

Comment: So you're unable to open the page in a regular browser either?  Have you tried `http://127.0.0.1/test.html` as well?

Comment: I copied and pasted that and got the same object not found error and I tried it with http://127.0.0.1/page.html as well. No good.  but if I double click on the page.html icon it opens in firefox.

Comment: It goes to the xampp for linux webpage and it adds xampp to the address as in http://localhost/xampp/

Comment: That's a good sign; at least we know your server is up and running.  You mentioned that if you double click on page.html in Eclipse it opens up in Firefox.  But what address does Firefox use to open it?  I'm wondering if Firefox is just opening it as a local file rather than loading it from your web server.

Comment: I figured it out thanks jSTiffs I found a another lammp/htdocs file deeper in the file structure Then I had to change permissions to be able to write to that file and now its working. Thanks alot for you help